# Measuring 3rd party Windows application network usage without installing additional tools

Tags: windows, networking, performance-monitoring

I need to measure network usage per client of a 3rd party application on a Windows server with following limitations:

1. I can't install additional software since this is a production server.
2. I need to be able to record traffic over period of time lets say 9 hours every day for a week.
3. I need a breakdown of traffic by client address and server port since I have multiple instances of application running on a single server

Here is what I looked into so far:

- I tried "Netsh Trace Capture" in combination with "Microsoft Message Analyzer" and it looks good - but it generates almost unmanageable amounts of data. As far as I know, when capturing, Netsh can't filter by port, if it could that would solve a problem for me.
- I looked into "Performance Monitor" but I was unable to obtain the necessary breakdowns from the recorded data.
- I also looked into "Resource Monitor" and effectively what it shows in the Network Tab would pretty much satisfy my requirements, but it has no recording capabilities that I was able to find.

What would be the suggested method to tackle this?
Is for example Netsh able to aggregate data while capturing?
Are there possibly portable tools that could act as a fronted for Netsh?

Edit:
In meantime I figured out that in Windows 10 port filtering is available in Netsh - but due to server operating system versions (WS 2008 R2 and WS2012) it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filters in combination with `netsh trace capture`. For example: `netsh trace start InternetClient provider=Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP level=5 keywords=ut:ReceivePath,ut:SendPath`

For more information, give a look at [the netsh trace manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129382(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to switch the server is connected to you can do a Port Mirror and apply the filters needed on the capture machine.

Comment: Unfortunately the server is at a hosting provider, so no physical access is possible whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the ISP host (hosting provider, OP sounds like this is a web app), there's a pretty good chance that they provide at least some lite tools for monitoring traffic, possibly in a GUI already loaded. If you have access to tweak the site, maybe consider Google Analytics.

Comment: It is not a web application, it is Microsoft Dynamics NAV. We have monitoring and we are aware of traffic in general. What I need is breakdown by client, and our hosting provider is not able to provide that.

Comment: I would highly suggest that you contact Microsoft support, it should be included with your software plan. I am sure they can resolve your reporting need without too much difficulty https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/contact-us